# Calling a function from Oracle forms

Tags: oracle, function, package, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracleforms

I am using Oracle Forms 6i with Oracle db 10g on a Windows machine, in a form, when i click on a button, the trigger WHEN-BUTTON-PRESSED is launched calling a function of a package in the database, Here is the PL/SQL code for both the trigger and the function:

The function:

```
Function test_function (code Varchar2) RETURN Varchar2 IS
BEGIN
    if code IN ('Y') then
        return('Yes');
    else 
        return('no');
    endif;
END;
```

The trigger:

```
DECLARE
    message_test varchar2(20);
BEGIN
    message_test := pkg_test.test_function('Y');
    message('the message is: ' || message_test);pause;
END;
```

My problem here is that it doesn't show anything, but when i write `pkg_test.test_function('Y')` in sql*plus or in SqlDevelopper it shows `'Yes'` as a result,

Or when i change `message_test := pkg_test.test_function('Y');` with `select pkg_test.test_function('Y') into message_test from test;` it works also.

what might be the cause of that?

PS: this is just a test code, the actual code is more complex than that.

Comment: Is your output blank? Or does it show "the message is: " and no message? Because if it's the first one, then your message() function isn't doing anything, but if it's the second one, the problem's with calling pkg_test.test_function().

Comment: @kfinity it's blank, there is no "the message is: ", the problem's with calling pkg_test.test_function().

Comment: Hmm, maybe you're getting an error? You could change the end of the trigger to: `EXCEPTION when others then message(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace); END;` to see what it is.

Comment: @kfinity "message(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace)" does not work in oracle forms!

Comment: @zenami then, try following in **pkg_test.test_function** (not in trigger): `exception when others then begin rollback;  raise_application_error(-20710,'My problem is '||dbms_utility.format_error_stack||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace||'['||dbms_utility.port_string||']'); end;` By the way, why word `pause;` stands there ?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan  I added the exception when other to my existent exception:

`EXCEPTION
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 
     RETURN('-');
   WHEN TOO_MANY_ROWS THEN  
     RETURN('Error');
   WHEN others THEN
   rollback;
   raise_application_error(-20710,'My problem is '||dbms_utility.format_error_stack||dbms_utility.format_erro‌​r_backtrace||'['||db‌​ms_utility.port_stri‌​ng||']');
   
END;`

And it's giving me the error: **PLS-00103**

Comment: @zenami remove `exception` just before `when others`. i.e. you should use `exception` clause only once.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan I used it only once in the beggining of the clause, i don't see what else you mean.

Comment: @zenami ok, excuse me, i've seen wrongly.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan So what is the problem here? why does it give me that error?

Answer (score 0):

If it is just test, Can you try show alert () function ?

```
DECLARE
    message_test varchar2(20);
    alert_resp number;
BEGIN
    message_test := pkg_test.test_function('Y');
    set_alert_property('ALERT_OK','the message is: ' || message_test);
    alert_resp := show_alert('ALERT_OK');
END;
```

Make sure that you create alert ALERT_OK in your forms alerts.

Comment: 'Show_alert' has only one argument which is the name/id of the alert, so this line isn't working "alert_resp := show_alert('ALERT_OK','the message is: ' || message_test);"